# rsync to copy only new files from a source having some of its files missing

Tags: rsync

Recently, I used `rsync` to copy a big directory with lots of files and sub-directories to an external HDD. Some files had too long file names and `rsync` couldn't copy them. After truncating the problematic file names, now I want to copy the resulting new files.

The source directory has some if its files deleted by me, but I don't want anything in the destination directory be deleted by `rsync`. I want them remaining intact without being mirrored to the source, while having the new files at the source copied and finally, having all the files that are common between the source and destination removed from the source (`--remove-from-source`).

`rsync -nrhtPsv --stats --ignore-existing --remove-source-files /run/media/username/hdd1/DIR1 /run/media/username/external_hdd`

As far as I know, `--ignore-existing` and `--remove-source-files` are not compatible with each other.

`--ignore-existing` and `--update` in the dry-run don't show any info on having anything removed/deleted, but both list the path of directories with missing files.

What command would do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of criteria:

- *I don't want anything in the destination directory be deleted by `rsync`* - do not specify `--delete`
- *I want […] new files at the source copied* - as usual
- *Having all the files that are common between the source and destination removed from the source* - use `--remove-source-files`

What you haven't mentioned is whether existing files in the destination should be updated or not, so I've assumed that they should.

The resulting command should be as follows,

```
rsync --dry-run -rt -Phv --stats --remove-source-files /run/media/username/hdd1/DIR1 /run/media/username/external_hdd
```

(Remove `--dry-run` to execute the changes rather than just viewing them.)

The problem you have with `--ignore-existing --remove-source-files` is that `--ignore-existing` is implemented as an exclusion rule. This means that files existing on the target are ignored, but because they are ignored they cannot be candidates for `--remove-source-files`. Depending on your situation you could use `--backup --remove-source-files` and then on the destination reinstate the backups:

```
find /run/media/username/external_hdd -type f -name '*~' -exec sh 'for f in "$@"; do echo mv -f "${f} "${f%~}"; done' _ {} +
```

(Remove `echo` to execute the renames rather than just viewing them.)

Comment: Thank you. But not sure about "whether existing files in the destination should be updated or not"... Is it about using the `--update` flag? Would `rsync` calculate and compare checksums to identify updated files?

Comment: @SeppA,`rsync` avoids calculating checksums whenever it feels it's "safe" to do so. In your case it will use file size and date/time last modified to decide if the files have changed or not.